# Why is my clean target getting executed?

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile.  However, I notice that intermediate build results are being removed from T2OUT.  Is this normal/expected behaviour?

```
BUILDROOT=../../..
T2OUT=$(BUILDROOT)/t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default
TUNDRA2=cd $(BUILDROOT); tundra2 production
DOCKER_TAG=services

SERVICES=managerservice \
    schedulerservice \
    paymentservice \
    userservice \
    storageservice \
    libModCouchbase.so 

all: $(SERVICES)
    chmod +x wait_to_start.sh
    docker build -t $(DOCKER_TAG) .
    docker push $(DOCKER_TAG)

$(T2OUT)/libModCouchbase.so:
    $(TUNDRA2) ModCouchbase

$(T2OUT)/%: 
    $(TUNDRA2) $*

%: $(T2OUT)/%
    cp $< $@

clean: 
    rm -f $(SERVICES)
    rm -rf $(T2OUT)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: Yes, [intermediate files get removed](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html). It has nothing to do with your `clean` target.

Comment: And if it is a problem you can preserve the intermediates with the `.PRECIOUS` symbolic target. Adding the `.PRECIOUS: foo` rule to your makefile will prevent intermediate `foo` from being deleted.